# AttributeError: module 'shutil' has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python-3.5, shutil

I have run to a wired error in `python 3.5`. I appreciate your help.

I want to copy some images from one directory to another directory using `shutil`. As I know, `shutil` is a standard library (doesn't need to be installed). But it doesn't work properly. How can I reinstall it or fix the error?

```
import shutil
import os
import random

##  This program copy some images of a folder randomly into an existed directory

src = "/FirstPath/BIODI_V3_175x100/Train_set/"
dist = "/SecondPath/Random_Images_of_BIODI_for_test/"
copied = 0
mlist = os.listdir(src)
#os.mkdir(dist)
for i in range(1000):
    rand = random.randint(1,len(mlist))
    shutil.copy((os.path.join(src,mlist[rand])),dist)
    i += 1
```

And it is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eshan/PycharmProjects/MTL_BIODI_backup/copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tarfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 49, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/eshan/PycharmProjects/MTL_BIODI_backup/copy.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copy((os.path.join(src,mlist[rand])),dist)
AttributeError: module 'shutil' has no attribute 'copy'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 44, in <module>
    import shutil as _shutil
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tarfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 49, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/eshan/PycharmProjects/MTL_BIODI_backup/copy.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copy((os.path.join(src,mlist[rand])),dist)
AttributeError: module 'shutil' has no attribute 'copy'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eshan/PycharmProjects/MTL_BIODI_backup/copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import tarfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tarfile.py", line 49, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/eshan/PycharmProjects/MTL_BIODI_backup/copy.py", line 15, in <module>
    shutil.copy((os.path.join(src,mlist[rand])),dist)
AttributeError: module 'shutil' has no attribute 'copy'
```